# How to fix scrapy.utils.http deprecated warning

Tags: scrapyd

I am getting depreciation error while trying to scrapy deploy. Pretty new at this scraping.

deploy.py:23: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.utils.http` is deprecated, Please import from `w3lib.http nstead. from scrapy.utils.http import basic_auth_header
unknown target: local

Any help apreciated

Comment: Did you solve this? Remember how?

Answer (score -3):

feedback said "please import from w3lib.http.nstead", so i guess you need to modify the file "scrapyd-deploy"